# INI style configuration file syntax check with Perl

Tags: perl, ini

Needs to ensure users provided INI file is clean from syntax error, such as

a) Unexpected syntax

```
[general]zzz
name=test
```

b) Non-filled column

```
[custom]
name=
```

Can i know if anyway we can check this?

Comment: You seemed to have forgotten to ask a question

Comment: Yes. We can check this.

Comment: INI is intentionally a very lenient self-correcting format like HTML. The first example is generally either a key named `zzz\nname` or a key named `zzz` with no value, and the second is a key with an empty value. You could throw an error if any key contains a newline or any value is an empty string. Alternatively Config::INI::Reader is a bit stricter (but it will still accept the second example because that's a perfectly valid empty string value).

Comment: in this case zzz has no '=' sign will that consider a valid key, and it is separated with '\n' with name. however Tiny config give me no warning and error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser!  There's quite a couple of INI-style config parsers at CPAN:

https://metacpan.org/search?q=config+ini

Comment: I am actually using Config Tiny parser for my work, however, i do not find anything that i can check on the syntax prior to use it, the parser will give me wrong data if the syntax is not right. that is the reason why i want to check it before feed into the parser.

Comment: @user1550596 What exactly do you mean by "the syntax is not right"?

Comment: please check my example above like if zzz there is no '=' so this might not be right, but config tiny will not report any warning or error.